# SQL - return each column and it's sum as rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have a table like this:

```
date | employee_id | field1 | field2 | field3 | ... | fieldN
```

I need a select which will return something like:

```
field1 | SUM(field1)
field2 | SUM(field2)
field3 | SUM(field3)
...
fieldN | SUM(fieldN)
```

Basically I need the field's name and it's sum. Is it possible with a sql query?

PS: If it's not possible to get the field's name and it's sum dynamically, I can type them 1 by 1 (they're about 20).

Comment: Which dbms you are using ?

Comment: Using SQLite and Qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to unpivot the data and do the aggregation

Here is an ANSI SQL method

```
select 'field1',sum(field1)
from yourtable 
union all
select 'field2',sum(field2)
from yourtable 
..
select 'fieldn',sum(fieldn)
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want each value on a separate row, then `union all` comes to mind:

```
select 'field1', sum(field1) from t union all
select 'field2', sum(field2) from t union all
. . .
```

However, I would recommend putting the values in a single row:

```
select sum(field1) as sum_field1, sum(field2) as sum_field2, . . .
from t;
```

The performance is much better because the table only needs to be read once.

If you like you can construct such a query from the metadata tables.  For instance, you could run:

```
select replace('select ''[c]'' as field, sum([c]) as [c] from t union all ', '[c]', column_name)
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = <whatever> and column_name like 'field%';
```

Then copy the code and tweak it into a valid SQL statement (by removing the final `union all`).

(In some databases, the metadata tables/views have different names, but `information_schema.column` is standard).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
select
    (select sum(field1) from tbl) as sum_field1,
    (select sum(field2) from tbl) as sum_field2,
    (select sum(field3) from tbl) as sum_field3,
    (select sum(field4) from tbl) as sum_field4,
    ...
    (select sum(fieldN) from tbl) as sum_fieldN
```